# What are NuGet API usage limits?

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

Are there any limits to using NuGet API through NuGet.Core library?

I am writing an application that maybe sending a lot of requests.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Nuget.Server` is open source and could be implemented by anyone, it would depend on the specific implementation. But I think you're referring to the Nuget Gallery at nuget.org.

In nuget.org's [terms of service](http://www.nuget.org/policies/Terms):

> User may not [...] subject the Web site's network or servers to unreasonable traffic loads, or otherwise engage in conduct deemed disruptive to the ordinary operation of the Web site

But, I couldn't find any specific usage limits. But obviously if you put nuget.org in danger, I think they would take all measures necessary to stop that traffic.